# HttpWebRequest build a custom request?

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest

Basically I have HttpListener to get the request from the client. Now I want to send that request with HttpWebRequest. Is there an easy way to take my raw HTTP request from HttpListener and set it all or will I have to make a parser of some sort to set it bit by bit? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to map them yourself, which isn't that much work.

Initially my thought was to use something like AutoMapper to map them, but the properties of the two classes are too different to map them automatically.